# $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ defined in polar coordinates by $-\pi<\theta<\pi$ and $r>1$. Prove $u=\theta$ is not Lipschitz continuous in $\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, lipschitz-functions

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the open set defined in polar coordinates by $-\pi<\theta<\pi$ and $r>1$. I have to prove that the function $u=\theta$ is not Lipschitz continuous in $\Omega$. How can I explicitly see this is true? I tried using the definition of Lipschitz continuous but I can't go anywhere from there.

Comment: Intuitively, a function is Lipschitz if it has bounded slope.  Now think about the graph of $u = \theta$, and think about where the slope becomes unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider $u(-2+ih) - u(-2-ih)$ as $h\to 0^+.$